# How can I add specialties like PRI and AI to tables in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to be able to connect my C# code to my MSSQL Database. Before I am able to do that I will have to add specialties like PRI and AI to certain columns in the tables.

I do not know how to add PRI and AI to certain columns though. I have tried looking in properties and everything, but I can not seem to find a way to add PRI and AI to certain columns.

Can someone with knowledge about MSSQL help me out with this?
This is what my table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Extra info: Sorry if my description of the problem is not understandable, so please mention that if there are any misunderstandings.

Comment: PRI means?? Primary key??

Comment: @RoyalNil: You mean you have already created table but you are not able to add these two columns "PRI" and "AI" thru SSMS right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming PRI stands for "primary key" and AI stands for "Automatic increment", 
to set a primary key, right click on the row and select "Set primary key", to set a column to increment automatically, set "identity specification" = "yes".
My suggestion is to skip the designer and write SQL Code instead.
That would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1
(
   cit          int identity(1,1) primary key,
   confignaam   varchar(255) null
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: Thank you very much this has helped me for my school project.